# Laravel Eloquent: Name attributes and db rows differently

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-3

I've just started to create an application using the Laravel framework for the first time.

Eloquent seems to be a very powerful and code-saving tool, but I can't figure out how to use different attribute names in the model than in the database table.

Here my conflict:

**Database**: iddog, dtname, dtbirth, dtfoo, fimom, fidad
**Attributes**: id, name, birth, foo, mom, dad

Is there a possibility to do that in a model that extends from Eloquent in the Laravel framework? Naming attributes differently than the associated database fields?

Or isn't it cool anymore to call fields in a database table like I do here?

Thank's in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why have different names for the database to your model?

Although you can do it - your just creating work for yourself, and introducing possible new bugs. Just use the database names.

If you must - check out [Getters & Setters](http://laravel.com/docs/database/eloquent#getter-and-setter-methods).

Comment: I always use a specific name convention when modeling database tables which I don't want in my models. I'll rename the database table. Ty for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Now, with laravel 5.1 we call it **Accessor** instead of Getters & Setters.

So these days we have Accessor that create new attributes like this

```
public function getPlusFiveAttribute()
{
    return $this->plus_five + 5;
}
```

Unfortunately if you already have a table field named 'plus_five ' - this Accessor will not work.

You need to go like this, it **works**:

```
public function getPlusFiveAttribute()
{
    return $this->attributes['plus_five'] + 5;
}
```

Here is another approach that **works**:

```
public function getPlusFiveAttribute($value)
{
    return $value + 5;
}
```

Comment: These are accessors. And in your first example it would be better to be `$this->attributes['plus_five'] + 5`.

Comment: Thanks!. $this->attributes['plus_five'] + 5 - worked and it is a new syntax. Great. And it is accessors, not mutators, you are right. I changed the answer. Thanks again.